# Declaration statements in C

Tags: c, declaration

I seem to have a problem with declarations screwing up my math. Any advice or suggestions are highly welcomed.

Here's the code:

```
int num1, num2, num3, num4, op, ;
    op = ((1==num3) || (2==num4)); 
    num3 = (num1 + num2);
    num4 = (num1 * num2);
```

I've been trying lots of arrangements and re-assignments. A lot has compiled, but when 5 + 5 = 2659043, there's a problem...

Comment: What is the goal of this code? Also, the last comma on the first line shouldn't be there. Did this code snippet even compile?

Comment: Several things here... What's the error? This won't compile. and You don't seem to be assigning any values to these variables, so performing arithmetic on uninitialized variables is of course going to give you some wild numbers.

Comment: Could you please give some context for this code?  Like the function that it's part of, and how it's being called.

Comment: If you are still learning how to program, I would recomend you at least have a look at a more newbie-friendly language, like [Python](http://www.python.org). It is very easy to get "weird problems" in C if you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but this is what your code is doing:

```
int num1, num2, num3, num4, op, ;
```

This line informs the C compiler that it needs to allocate space for 5 integers (num1, num2, num3, num4, op), these integers can now be used as variables until the scope expires. Not sure why you have the last ',' you might want to remove that.

```
op = ((1==num3) || (2==num4));
```

If num3 is 1, or num4 = 2, then set op to 1 (true). Otherwise, set op to 0 (false).

```
num3 = (num1 + num2);
```

Self-explanatory: Add num1 and num2 and put the sum into num3.

```
num4 = (num1 * num2);
```

Self explanatory: Multiply num1 and num2 and put the product into num4.

Immediately I see an issue with your program. You are using these variables, but have not initialized them to anything. For example, how is there supposed to be a sum of (num1 + num2) if num1 and num2 do not have a value. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int num1, num2, sum;
   num1 = 1;
   num2 = 2;
   sum = num1 + num2;

   printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: I basically want the variable "op" to point to either the num1 or num2 function, depending on the input of "1" or "2", assigned through "op".

Comment: Okay people, thanks for those finer points. I'm a newb, yes. I'm having fun. I like C. I have programmed before, but that was a while ago. As for the context of the code, Here's the whole thing after multiple tweeks as recomended.

Comment: @MichaelO'hearn In most programming languages, you tell the computer to do a sum, it will do it, then it will be lazy and not re-do the calculation if the numbers change. You said that you wanted a function: that's an actual thing in programming languages. You can take the numbers as input and return an output, then run the function once you've got some data.

Answer (score 2):

Okay... there's a lot wrong here, but I'll go through what you posted in the comments point by point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  /*Declare the active agents */
  int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0, num4=0, op = 1 || 2 ;
```

You initialize your variables to zero here, except op, which you set to 1 (1 || 2, which is the boolean or, will return 1 (true), so as a result you set op to 1).

```
  num3 = (num1 + num2);
  num4 = (num1 * num2);
```

Here you set num3 and num4 both to zero, since num1 + num2 is 0 + 0 and num1 * num2 is 0 * 0. You want to move this down after your scanf's.

```
  /* Information Extraction Method */
  printf("YO MOFO!!!Press a number or hit the dirt!!\n");
  scanf("%d", &num1);
  printf("Since you didn't hit the dirt, how about another number?\n");
  scanf("%d", &num2);

  /* Menu (AKA Input */
  printf("If you want to add, press 1 ,\nIf you want to multiply, press 2 ... \n\n ");
  scanf ("%d", &op);
```

These printf's and scanf's are good. Good job.

```
  /* PROCESS */
  if (op = 1) {num3;};
  if (op = 2) {num4;};
```

Three things here. First, op = 1 is assigning 1 to op. Same with op = 2. You want op == 1 and op == 2 as you have below. The result of this will be that op will always be 2 after these if statements.

The second thing is that, while a valid statement, num3; by itself won't do anything.

Finally, while it doesn't hurt anything, you don't need semicolons after your closing curly braces.

```
  /* OutPut */
  if (op == 1) {
    printf("Alone, a toothpick is weak, but as part of a sum, your answer is:\n%d"), &num3;
  };

  if (op == 2) {
    printf("Multiplied as a sum of it's parts, your answer is:\n%d"), &num4;
  };
```

Here you're printing out the address of num3 and num4 instead of their values. This is part of the reason you're seeing large numbers that don't make sense, it's the address of num3 and num4 in memory. Only scanf needs the ampersand (&), printf does not. Also, as it stands, the actual value of these will always be 0 since your calculations are done before you get the numbers from the user.

EDIT: Actually, it turns out the reason you aren't getting the right numbers here is that you aren't passing the number to printf at all. You have num3 and num4 outside of the parentheses. There still shouldn't be an ampersand before the variable name, but it should look like this `printf("Multiplied... is:\n%d", num4);` Notice how `num4` is inside the parentheses.

```
  printf("\n\n\n\nMath frum da hud..... Yo. \n\n\nLOL\n >;]");

  /* End Of Program */
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: For clarity's sake, I've re-written it in a manner such that it should work the way you intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  /*Declare the active agents */
  int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0, num4=0, op = 0;

  /* Information Extraction Method */
  printf("YO MOFO!!!Press a number or hit the dirt!!\n");
  scanf("%d", &num1);
  printf("Since you didn't hit the dirt, how about another number?\n");
  scanf("%d", &num2);

  num3 = (num1 + num2);
  num4 = (num1 * num2);      

  /* Menu (AKA Input */
  printf("If you want to add, press 1 ,\nIf you want to multiply, press 2 ... \n\n ");
  scanf ("%d", &op);

  /* OutPut */
  if (op == 1) {
    printf("Alone, a toothpick is weak, but as part of a sum, your answer is:\n%d", num3);
  };

  if (op == 2) {
    printf("Multiplied as a sum of it's parts, your answer is:\n%d", num4);
  };

  printf("\n\n\n\nMath frum da hud..... Yo. \n\n\nLOL\n >;]");

  /* End Of Program */
  return 0;
}
```

HTH.

Comment: @Armbrat It's deleted now, but this was the OP's code, not mine. So thank him for the hilarity. :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the variables, so their values are undefined (and probably not 0). You should initialize (like that, for example):

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, op = 0 ;
```

Comment: I tried to initialize the variables this way, but math functions still don't work. I am resolving this discussion as answered. This is because I was to vague in my description, due to my lack of experience with such forums...